# Понятие поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Что означает поговорка "Одна только сваха за чужие души божится"?

Answer (score 1):

Сваха, выполняя свою работу, божится, что "купец" или "товар" у неё что надо, и родители их, ей-богу, люди хорошие,  обещает счастливую семейную жизнь, богатство и т.д. Она божится, то есть ссылается на Бога, чтобы ей поверили, хотя очень часто она преувеличивает достоинства людей, о которых говорит. Упоминать Бога всуе не принято, вот и говорят: "Одна только сваха за чужие души божится". Я так понимаю эту поговорку.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, конечно, можно увидеть некий подтекст на тему "не упоминай Бога всуе", но тогда теряется "чужие души", а это здесь ключевое. Чужая душа - потемки, это и есть основной смысл поговорки. Никто не должен божиться за другого, нет у смертных такого таланта наверняка знать, что у того под черепной коробкой...

Answer (score 0):

Одна сваха чужу сторону нахваливает (а сама дома сидит).